Permission Denied on .git/objects/pack/tmp_pack issue with GIT Clone or Fetch from Azure DevOps
I’m not sure I can give a lot of information on how to reproduce this error. I’ve searched online and can’t see anything specific to this error.
I work in an organisation which is very restrictive, we have a custom Windows 10 build for example.
We have an on-premises Azure DevOps server where we store our GIT repos. We have an annoying issue where we will sometimes get an error which basically says:
Fatal: could not open ‘.git/objects/pack/tmp_pack_gdura’ for reading: Permission denied.
Fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output

We want to use a windows file server to store the git repos and it’s working fine on other repositories and has worked fine on some repositories for a while. I’ve set up a space on a Linux server and get the same issue.
I’ve checked and checked permissions they are all fine.
I tried to change the authentication to Azure DevOps to HTTPS or SSH but that’s sitting with organisational ICT as it’s not enabled currently.
I’ve tried to also use the IP address directly of the Linux server in case it was a DNS type of issue.
Using Visual Studio or GIT Bash with my computers local C drive works fine 100% of the time, but we don’t want to use that location.
Apologies I can not provide much more due to sensitivity.
Thanks in advance for any insight some one may have.

May i know when did the error report? What operation or command did you do?  As you mentioned, will sometimes get an error, looks like it's intermittent, if you repeat the same operation again, will it happen? In addition, please check similar link.

If you git pull the repo again, will it succeed? If not, you can delete the pack file, and git pull to get all files again, then have a check.

@wadezhou-MSFT it’s intermittent by means of the repository, some work some don’t. If I try to clone the repo new I get the error to either a windows file server or the Linux machine, but will work fine to the local C drive. Some repositories will not allow me to fetch either.

Since it's always working with Visual Studio or Git bash with local C drive, which means the repo server is working fine. You can change the visual studio location or git bash folder to the file server, will the issue happen too? If the issue persists, mostly it's caused by fille server or interrupted transition by bad network. In addition, as stated before, please repeat the same operation, confirm if it could succeed or always failed.
